# Change colors in scatterplot by category

Tags: python, colors, seaborn, scatter-plot

I am wondering how I can change the colors of my categories manually in the python code under instead of using cmap?

The colors I want is the following hex color codes:

Blue: #1f77b4

Orange: #ff7f0e

Green: #2ca02c

Red: #d62728

```html
d = """category1,05-01-2020
category1,02-02-2020
category3,06-03-2020
category2,12-04-2020
category4,07-05-2020

"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(d), sep=',', parse_dates=[1], header=None, names=['category','date'])


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(df['date'],df['category'], marker='s', c=df['category'].astype('category').cat.codes, cmap='tab10')
```

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for including the sample data!
[Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/index.html) has `hue` and `palette` keyword arguments that make this quite simple.

```
import seaborn as sns

df = df.sort_values('category')
sns.scatterplot('date','category',marker='s',data=df,
                hue='category',palette=['#1f77b4','#ff7f0e','#2ca02c','#d62728'])
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]

---

If you want to stay with vanilla Matplotlib you can do:

```
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('custom_colors',
                                         ['#1f77b4','#ff7f0e','#2ca02c','#d62728'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
ax.scatter(df['date'],df['category'], marker='s', 
           c=df['category'].astype('category').cat.codes, cmap=cmap)
```